# Making Audio capturer and Audio player ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-audio

I have sucessfully made Audio Capturer and Audio Player using audio unit.
Now my requirement is to make a conference call where i have one audio Capturer but multiple audio Players ...When testing i can only hear sound from one player. Can i make Multiple player with single audio unit ? Plz help

Comment: Can you put some code of what you tried.  Are you trying to record a phone conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear PCM and IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) You can play multiple linear PCM or IMA4 sounds simultaneously in iOS without incurring CPU resource problems. The same is true for the iLBC speech-quality format, and for the µ-law and a-law compressed formats. When using compressed formats, check the sound quality to ensure it meets your needs. [Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html)

Using Linear PCM it should be able to play simultaneously.

Another solution I can think of is use a Mixer Audio Unit and send all your players to the Mixer and play the output.